# Xcode ERROR ITMS-90783: “Missing bundle display name”

Tags: xcode, jenkins, app-store, testflight

Today I started to receive the build error with Jenkins.

> Missing bundle display name

I have `CFBundleName` already in the info.plist.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a new change by Apple. Some thoughts also here https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/c6bx5f/why_am_i_getting_error_itms90783_missing_bundle/

Comment: I also received this error and added it manually, I thought it was a local bug so thank you for the link and clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode ERROR ITMS-90783: "Missing bundle display name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807112/xcode-error-itms-90783-missing-bundle-display-name)